# Problem connecting to Webmin-Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, server, permissions, webmin

Webmin is stopped,

Any suggestions?

```
admin@ubuntu_1604:~$ service webmin status
● webmin.service - LSB: Start or stop the Webmin server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/webmin; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since mié 2017-01-11 13:28:10 CET; 1 day 4h ago

admin@ubuntu_1604:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/webmin status
Webmin is stopped

admin@ubuntu_1604:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/webmin restart 
Stopping Webmin server in /usr/share/webmin
cat: /var/webmin/miniserv.pid: No such file or directory
/etc/webmin/stop: 4: kill: Usage: kill [-s sigspec | -signum | -sigspec] [pid | job]... or
kill -l [exitstatus]
Starting Webmin server in /usr/share/webmin
Pre-loaded WebminCore
Failed to open socket family 10 : Bad file descriptor at /usr/share/webmin/miniserv.pl line 542.

sudo update-rc.d webmin defaults
insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (0 1 4 6) of script `webmin' overrides LSB defaults (0 1 6).
insserv: script webminbackup: service webmin already provided!

admin@ubuntu_1604:~$ sudo find /etc/ -iname webmin
[sudo] password for admin: 
/etc/pam.d/webmin
/etc/init.d/webmin
/etc/webmin
/etc/webmin/webmin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems experienced would occur to me when installing the latest version of webmin, currently the version 1.831 with the version 1.820 I have managed to solve the problem.

I followed the next steps:

1. Remove the current Webmin installation:

   ```
   sudo apt purge --autoremove webmin
   ```
2. Download the [`webmin_1.820_all.deb` file](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/webadmin/webmin_1.820_all.deb).
3. After downloading the file install it with:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i webmin_1.820_all.deb
   ```

Keep in mind to have all dependencies installed for this package.

After installing this version I have been able to update to the last version without any problem.